# Coldfusion - how to deliver different content for mobiles (at server level)

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way for coldfusion to reliably detect when the user is on a mobile (narrow screen) device (so I can deliver different content to them).

I appreciate I can use css media queries to change how the content is displayed (or not) but I would ideally like to re-order some of my blocks of content and also not send some larger content to mobile users.

ie

```
    [cfif user_is_on_a_mobile]

        small content 

    [cfelse]

        large content

    [/cfif]
```

Thanks very much indeed.

Nick

Comment: ALthough the solution offered by Kwispel will work, i would strongly recommend not designing different layouts for different devices. Changing the layout becomes a hassle when working with multiple templates offering the same data. We used to have a layout for mobile users and desktop users for all our websites but we stopped this because a lot of mobile users still preferred the desktop version and it took a lot of time to maintain the mobile versions.

Comment: I have three words for you - [responsive web design](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=responsive+web+design)

Comment: Hi Nebu - it's a fair point you make. I'm mostly going to use it for swapping the running order of content (where we have it on the right on a desktop but want it at the top on mobile) - and a bit to supply reduced content (less data for user to download). Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://detectmobilebrowsers.com - it has a CF script you can use to detect mobile browsers.

Comment: That script looks high maintenance.

Comment: Thanks Kwispel. Does anyone have any comments as to the overhead of having that (fairly involved) regex running on ever page of a site?